# Django error: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'toppings'

Tags: django, django-models, save, m2m

On the admin UI, after fillings the fields and pressing the 'save' button, I get this error
Can anyone tell me what is the issue?  From what I have read, this issue is often caused by not putting this line of code `super(Pizza, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`, yet I still get this error and am unable to understand why

FYI: I want to make each Pizza to have a default Topping of Cheese, and this for all Pizza and it should not be able to remove it

```
class Topping(models.Model):                                                                                         
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)                                                                           

    def __str__(self):                                                                                               
        return(f"{self.name}")                                                                                       


class Pizza(models.Model):                                                                                           
    PIZZA_SIZES = (                                                                                                  
        ('S', 'Small'),                                                                                              
        ('L', 'Large'),                                                                                              
    )                                                                                                                

    pizza_type = models.CharField(max_length=64)                                                                     
    pizza_size = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PIZZA_SIZES)                                                 
    qty_toppings = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(3)], default=0)           
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping)                                                                       
    price = models.IntegerField(help_text="Price in $")                                                              


    def __str__(self):                                                                                               
        return f"Size: {self.get_pizza_size_display()}, Type: {self.pizza_type}, Number of Toppings: {self.qty_toppi\
ngs},  Price: {self.price}, Toppings: {self.toppings.in_bulk()}"                                                     

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):                                                                                 
        # if 'toppings' not in kwargs:                                                                               
        # kwargs.setdefault('force_insert', True)                                                                    
        # kwargs.setdefault('force_update', True)                                                                    
        kwargs.setdefault('toppings', Topping.objects.get(name='Cheese'))                                            
        super(Pizza, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: You can do like this `self.toppings.add(Topping.objects.get(name='Cheese'))`.

Refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add related through M2M objects to record before it's save. Read [this doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) about M2M.

You can do as offered in comments:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):                                                                                                                                                                                          
    super(Pizza, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    self.toppings.add(Topping.objects.get(name='Cheese'))
```

Or you can set [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) signal:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=Pizza)
def update_stock(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.toppings.add(Topping.objects.get(name='Cheese'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works under the ```python manage.py shell```  
What about admin's UI? I'm assuming I have to override the ```admin's models save method```?

Comment: You rather looking for [save_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_related) admin model method.